How can I prevent infinity loop in useEffect
I have such code. Fisrt I need to fetch some statuses
  const { statuses } = useAppSelector((state) => state.refMaterial.data);
  const [requiredNames, setRequiredNames] = useState<Statuses>(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!statuses) dispatch(fetchStatuses());
  }, []);

Then I have to call some functions and call SetState action in other useEffect, but in it I run into infinity loop error. I tried to move out setState action of useEffect, and wrap it into a useCallback, but I still have infinity loop error. Here is the code
const setReqNames = useCallback(
    ({
      inWork,
      closed,
      hold,
      newStatus,
    }: {
      inWork: Status;
      closed: Status;
      hold: Status;
      newStatus: Status;
    }) => {
      setRequiredNames({
        inWork: inWork.alias,
        hold: hold.alias,
        closed: closed.alias,
        newStatus: newStatus.alias,
      });
    },
    []
  );

useEffect(() => {
    if (!statuses) return;
    const { inWork, hold, closed, newStatus } = getRequiredStatuses();
    setReqNames({ inWork, closed, newStatus, hold });
    getFromNewStatuses();
    getFromWorkStatuses();
    getFromHoldStatuses();
    getFromClosedStatuses();
  }, [statuses]);

I find out, that this function, that returns fields for selectButton by current status causes error.
const getButtonActionsByStatus = (onClick: OnClickFunction) => {
    if (!requiredNames) return [];
    switch (currentStatus) {
      case requiredNames.newStatus: {
        getFromNewStatuses(onClick);
        return fromNew;
      }
      case requiredNames.inWork: {
        getFromWorkStatuses(onClick);
        return fromWork;
      }
      case requiredNames.hold: {
        getFromHoldStatuses(onClick);
        return fromHold;
      }
      case requiredNames.closed: {
        getFromClosedStatuses(onClick);
        return fromClose;
      }
      default:
        return [];
    }
  };


Are you setting statuses in any of the functions within this useEffect hook?

@RAllen No, statuses from redux store

As a little comment, if statuses is an array/object or anything complex, you might be involuntarily re-running the effect if you add it into the dependency array in the case that the reference to statuses becomes different.

I fixed problem by removing functions, that changes state from the function
